# How to insert foreign key into MySQL database using PHP?

Tags: php, android, mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables: `users` and `orders`. I want to insert a foreign key (`unique_id` from users) to the table orders so that each order is represented by a different user.

PHP statement:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
              orders(id, unique_id, product, volume, type, crates, ordered_at)
              SELECT  VALUES
              ('$id', '$unique_id','$product', '$volume', '$type', '$crates', NOW())");
```

`unique_id` is the foreign key.

Comment: I think you're trying to do a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` - my guess is you have the syntax wrong. I think it's `INSERT INTO my_table (my_col) SELECT my_col FROM my_other_table`. Try copying your query into your database system and running it directly, and see if you get an error?

Comment: Or are you just trying to insert a FK value? If so, a regular `INSERT` needs you to remove the `SELECT` - that will just confuse the database engine.

Comment: when i key in this stmt i get an error INSERT INTO orders(id, unique_id, product, volume, type, crates, amount, ordered_at) VALUES('$id', '$unique_id',SELECT FROM unique_id from users, '$product', '$volume', '$type', '$crates', '$amount', NOW())

Comment: Any chance you might mention what error you are getting? I think it might be important.

Answer (score 1):

before this PHP issue first you have to create table properly using mysql. like as below
//I am just putting required fields.

```
create table users(unique_id int primary key,name varchar(50));

create table orders(id int primary key, unique_id int,foreign key(unique_id) references users(unique_id));
```

so whenever if you want to insert data which is not unique_id in users it will not take in orders.
If this much you have done then according to me you have to edit question because it is not clear enough.